# ListBox SelectedIndex as command paramter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

How Command parameter can be bind to the selected index in ListBox? My code:

```
<ListBox>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger
                EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction
                    Command="{
                              Binding Path=SelectPath,  
                              Mode=OneTime, 
                              RelativeSource={
                                            RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                            AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}
                                     }
                 }" 
                    CommandParameter="ListBox.SelectedIndex" // how can this parameter be bind to SelectedIndex
                    />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    </ListBox>
```

EDIT:

What I did and it works: created new dp property SelectedListBoxIndex bind it with SelectedIndex and then pass property as command parameter. But is there a better way to do it?

```
        <ListBox
        SelectedIndex="{
                    Binding Path=SelectedListBoxIndex,
                    RelativeSource={
                                    RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                    AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}
                                   }}">

        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger
                EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction
                    Command="{
                              Binding Path=SelectPath,  
                              Mode=OneTime, 
                              RelativeSource={
                                            RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                            AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}
                                     }
                 }"
                    CommandParameter="{
                    Binding Path=SelectedListBoxIndex,
                    RelativeSource={
                                    RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                    AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}
                                   }
                 }" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could be setting your ListBox x:Name and then binding CommandParameter to its SelectedIndex property like this:

```xaml
<ListBox x:Name="lb">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger
                EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction
                    Command="{
                              Binding Path=SelectPath,  
                              Mode=OneTime, 
                              RelativeSource={
                                            RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                            AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}
                                     }
                 }" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=lb, Path=SelectedIndex}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    </ListBox>
```

Comment: @iknow is this answer is correct, accept it using button to the left of the answer.